# Finding the calling functions address in Visual C++ (safely)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stack-trace

I am trying to find a safe way to get a calling functions address without doing any hacky stuff (like giving function address as an argument). Looking for a solution that should work for x86 and x64. Thanks.

```
void callingFunction() {
    helloWorld();
}

void helloWorld() {
    printf("Hello world! This function was called by 0x%X!\n", /* CALLING FUNCTION ADDRESS HERE */);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`helloWorld()` can't *directly* get the address of `callingFunction()` itself, only the address that `helloWorld()` will return to when it exits.  Visual C++ has [`_AddressOfReturnAddress()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/addressofreturnaddress) and [`_ReturnAddress()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/returnaddress) compiler intrinsic functions you can use to get that address, eg:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <intrin.h>  

void callingFunction() {
    helloWorld();
}

void helloWorld() {
    printf("Hello world! This function was called by %p!\n", *((void**) _AddressOfReturnAddress()));
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <intrin.h>  

#pragma intrinsic(_ReturnAddress)

void callingFunction() {
    helloWorld();
}

void helloWorld() {
    printf("Hello world! This function was called by %p!\n", _ReturnAddress());
}
```

If `helloWorld()` needs to know whether the return address belongs to `callingFunction()` specifically, the project will have to generate a [map file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7xkk3e2.aspx) that `helloWorld()` can then parse at runtime to get the starting and ending addresses of `callingFunction()`, and then it can check if the return address falls within that range or not.